# GDB configure script cant find expat, is there a way to specify where to find it?

Tags: gdb, centos7, expat-parser

OS: CentOS 7
GDB-7.11

I need GDB-7.11 because there is finally support for thread names to appear in the debugger on a remote debug session. I can not get the thread names to show up, however and I believe it is because when I run GDB I am getting the following:

```
warning: Can not parse XML target description; XML support was disabled at compile time
```

if i use: yum whatprovides libexpat

```
[root@localhost lib64]# yum whatprovides libexpat
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, fastestmirror, langpacks, nvidia
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.fdcservers.net
 * elrepo: ord.mirror.rackspace.com
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * epel-debuginfo: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: chicago.gaminghost.co
 * ius: ord.mirror.rackspace.com
 * ius-debuginfo: ord.mirror.rackspace.com
 * updates: mirror.sesp.northwestern.edu
expat-2.1.0-8.el7.i686 : An XML parser library
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Provides    : libexpat.so.1
```

it is clearly there, located in /usr/lib64

when i run ./configure --with-read-line --with-libexpat

```
.
.
.
checking whether to use expat... auto
checking for libexpat... (cached) no
configure: WARNING: expat is missing or unusable; some features may be unavailable.
.
.
.
```

so again, the question is, why can GDB's configure script not find it; it seems to find everything else...?

Comment: Install `expat-devel` package and rebuild gdb. This will fix `warning: Can not parse XML target description...`. Though I doubt it will fix thread names to show up.

Comment: @ks1322 Package expat-devel-2.1.0-8.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
:(

Comment: Looks like you misspelled expat configure option. Try `--with-expat` or remove it at all (it is enabled by default).

Comment: @ ks1322 you were right, libexpat is the wrong option. now, it simply fails correctly: configure: error: expat is missing or unusable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yum install expat-devel
```

(copied from @ks1322 comment)

The original error I observed was

```
checking for libexpat... no
configure: error: expat is missing or unusable
gmake[1]: *** [configure-gdb] Error 1
```

This error is strange because `yum install expat` installs shared library file `/usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1`.
The `yum install expat-devel` installs shared library file `/usr/lib64/libexpat.so`.  It appears GNU `configure` only searches for `libexpat.so`.

Answer (score 0):

The version of gdb 8.3 has the same problem.
I thought of various ways, but I still can't work.
In the end, I used the 10.2 version and all the problems were gone.